# Load gif image file to fast report picture box

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am using delphi 10 and fastreport. I want to load gif image file to fast report picture box in the code. The code that i have tried is below. same code for jpg or png is working fine.

```
TfrxPictureView(RptPatientProfileCat.FindObject('Picture1')).Picture.LoadFromFile('D:\T0000104.gif');
```

Comment: Are you sure FastReport supports jpg? From the manual it says: `The
object can display graphics in “BMP”, “JPEG”, “ICO”, “WMF” or “EMF” format.
`. Did you try asking in FastReport forum, [FastReport VCL 5](https://www.fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php?showforum=20)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask if you are sure that FastReport supports gif.

Comment: @LURD not yet. I will ask. thank you.